# How to `kubectl port-forward svc/myservice 1234:5678`

Tags: python, kubernetes

Wanna use python to port-forward a service at `5678` to my local port `1234`.

[connect_get_namespaced_pod_portforward](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#connect_get_namespaced_pod_portforward) only has the parameters `ports`. How can I pass different localhost port here?

Can I also use this to port-forward a service?

Comment: In k8s go-client we have [port-forward pack](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/cmd/portforward), but I'm not sure if there is a similar one for python. You can try `from kubernetes.stream import portforward` and `portforward.PortForwardOptions()` (I haven't tried it in Python but similar API works in go).